# execute function in js defined on other page vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I would like to execute a function in a Javascript file, since this same function is defined on another file, which is called Header.vue, I tried with module.export, but no result, the function in Header.vue is activated at the click of a button. I searched on Google and I think that module.export is only adapted between two .js files. my code is so below.

Header.vue :

```js
<template>
  <header id="header" class="flex">
    <h1>
      <a href="/">TEST</a>
    </h1>
    <ul class="control">
       
      <li>
        <button @click="next" :disabled="connectionState !== 'open'">Next</button>
      </li>
      
    </ul>
  </header>
</template>
 
<script>
import { mapState, mapMutations, mapActions } from 'vuex'
module.export  {
export default {
  name: 'app-header',
 
  computed: mapState(['localStream', 'connectionState']),
 
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['createPeerConnection', 'closePeerConnection', 'addLocalStream', 'removeLocalStream']),
    ...mapActions(['getUserMedia', 'hangUpCall']),
 
     
 
    next () {
      this.closePeerConnection()
      this.hangUpCall()
      this.createPeerConnection()
      this.addLocalStream(this.localStream)
    },
 
     
  }
}<br>};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

and test.js

```js
var common = require('./src/components/Header.vue');
1
 
common.next();<br><br>
```

Comment: Is your other component a sibling, parent or child component? There are multiple ways depending the hierarchy of your components. You could pass a function as a prop easy as 
```<ChildComponent :function="myFunction" />```

Comment: `common.next();<br><br>` you're mixing HTML and javascript -check the browser developer tools console for errors

Comment: thanks for your comments, how can i check if the other component is a sibling, parent or child component? and i will check the console to see errors